# JSONSerialization.jsonObject

Tags: ios, swift, nsjsonserialization

I'm new developing iOS with JSON Token and I'm getting an unsupported_grant_type error. The code that I am developing is the following

```
let params = ["grant_type": "password", "username": userEmail, "password": userPassword]

let url = URL(string: "http://test/SPUSR/Token")

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

try? request.httpBody = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])

let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any]

        self.token = json!!["access_token"] as? String
    }

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

With Postman everything works well. My API are developed under technolgy C#

Comment: Are you sure, it's `C#`?

Comment: Yes, i developed them

Comment: And where is C# code in your question? Where do you get an error? On client or server?

Comment: That is not C# in the question.

Comment: On client, when i test the API with Postman it works well but, when i try to connect with my iOS App i get the unsupported_grant_type error

Comment: Dont use `JSONSerialization` for httpBody, try convert directly the string to data to sent

Answer (score 0):

The message "unsupported_grant_type" explicitly tells you that your server doesn't expect that request. You're trying POST: "grant_type":"password", credentials in body - that means that content-type has to be "**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**". See Console in Postman.

Comment: IT was ok with your recommendation and thanks for your help; I have solve my problem